# Dynamically create vector based on the length of another vector

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to create a vector of keys to pass to assoc-in to describe where in a map the insert should take place. The second vector of an unknown size will dictate where I need to assoc-in based on its length.

For example if the length of the vector

- is 1) I will need to assoc-in [:aggs :bucket-aggregation :aggs]
- is 2) I will need to assoc-in [:aggs :bucket-aggregation :aggs :bucket-aggregation :aggs]

I have the following but can't get the vector to dynamically increase in size.

```
(vec (concat [:aggs] [:bucket-aggregation :aggs]))
```

Comment: How are you checking the size of the vector? Remember that vectors are immutable in Clojure and you need to use the value returned from `vec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to my understanding of your question, i would go with something like this:

```
user> (defn make-query [based-on-v]
        (vec
         (apply concat [:aggs]
                (repeat (count based-on-v) [:bucket-aggregation :aggs]))))
#'user/make-query

user> (make-query [1])
;;=> [:aggs :bucket-aggregation :aggs]

user> (make-query [1 2])
;;=> [:aggs :bucket-aggregation :aggs :bucket-aggregation :aggs]
```

Comment: `(vec (apply concat [:aggs] ...` could be `(into [:aggs] cat ...`

Comment: even better: `(reduce into [:aggs] (repeat ...))`